# Access rights on relational field such as one2many , many2many

Tags: python, odoo

I have tried & it's quite frustrating that I am not able to assign access rights to my customized module.

I am inheriting `stock.picking module`.

Following code:

```
class stock_picking(osv.osv):

    _inherit = 'stock.picking'    
    _description = "Picking List"

    _columns = {

            'comments_ids': fields.one2many(
                 'stock.picking.comments', 'stock_id', 'Driver Notes'),
    }       


stock_picking()    

class stock_picking_comments(osv.osv):

    _name = 'stock.picking.comments'
    _description = 'Driver Note'    
    _order = 'name desc'

    _columns = {
        'name': fields.datetime('Date'),
        'stock_id': fields.many2one('stock.picking', 'Delivery orders'),
        'comment': fields.text('Note'),
        'login_user': fields.char('Login User',size=100),
    }               

stock_picking_comments()
```

Now I create new group, assign user and access right as `READ` & `CREATE` to object `stock.picking.ads` but nothing is reflected. I am able to delete and write which should not happen. Very Strange!

Comment: don't know the module, but when you instantiate your classes you don't catch the reference to them into any variable. E.g. `sp = stock_picking()`

Comment: so it possible to give access rights to relational fields such as one2many?

Answer (score 0):

You need assign a group for your new field.

like, in your xml record you need to define group

```
<field name="comments_ids" groups="stock.group_stock_user"/>
```

It means that this field will get the access rights of `group_stock_user` for stock.picking model,

you need to define the model access for the group through `ir.model.access.csv` file.